# How do I prove “lim(x->0) sinx/(x+1)=0” with precies definition of a limit?

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin x}{x+1}=0$$

How do I prove the statement using $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of a limit?

There's a hint "$|\sin x|\leqslant |x|$", but I can't solve anymore

$$\frac{|\sin x|}{|x+1|} \leqslant \frac{|x|}{|x+1|} < \cdots$$

(don't know how to proceed)

Comment: $$\frac{\sin x}{x+1}\to \frac{0}1=0$$

Comment: Begin by writing down the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition.

Answer (score 3):

$\frac {|x|} {|1+x|} \leq \frac {|x|} {1-|x|} <\epsilon$ if $|x| <\delta$ where $\delta =\frac {\epsilon} {1+\epsilon}$.

Answer (score 0):

In the range $[-0.5,0.5]$ we have $1+x\ge0.5$ and

$$\left|\frac x{x+1}\right|\le 2|x|,$$ which squeezes the limit to $0$.